# Below are few words who appear extremly simple but have altogether very different meaning

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, ambiguity, gre

Broadside: it means "Verbal Attack"

Aboveboard: means "Honest"

Underwrite: means "Financial support"

Can you please help me understand what are these called?
I am aware of Homonyms and Homophones but obviously these words are something different.

I want to know their classification and of course some source where I can learn more about words like these (who appear different but mean different)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any collective name for the words you list. Their meanings have evolved over several centuries. To learn more about such words you need to consult a good dictionary that provides the derivations of words.

A **broadside** originally referred to all the guns along one side of a ship being fired together; the meaning of an angry verbal attack is a metaphor.

**Aboveboard** refers to card players keeping their hands above the table (that is, not cheating).

**Underwrite** presumably refers to someone signing their name to a legal document.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks very much

could you suggest few more words off the top of your head? who look like a combination of two simple words but mean completely different?

Comment: Dead right, Kate. I found [this reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/financial-word-origins/underwrite) on the Merriam Webster site which confirms your guess about underwriting.